# Reducer Custom Dispatch Type, is not assignable, Types of property ‘dispatch’ are incompatible

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-actions

I have a simple reducer & action types right now.  While setting up my tests, I am running into a type def issue with the return of my `store` in reference to my "custom" action type declarations.  I am seeing an error:

> Type ‘Store<CombinedState<{ global: GlobalStateShape; }>, SetSelectedAccount >’ is not assignable to type ‘Store<any, AnyAction>’.
> Types of property ‘dispatch’ are incompatible

I have followed the [Redux Typescript docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript) correctly AFAIK.

Why is `SetSelectedAccount` being returned when I invoke `combineReducers()`?  The `globalReducer` is handling action of `SetSelectedAccount`.

In my test setup File **where the error above occurs**:

```
export function createTestStore(isInternal: boolean): Store {
  const store: Store<CombinedState<{
    global: GlobalStateShape;
    }>, SetSelectedAccount> = createStore(rootReducer, { global: 
     getGlobalInitialState(isInternal) });
  return store;
}
```

**src/reducer.ts**

```
export const rootReducer: Reducer<CombinedState<{
    global: GlobalStateShape;
}>, SetSelectedAccount> = combineReducers({
  global: globalReducer,
});
```

**src/store.ts**

```
const composedEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(
  applyMiddleware()
);

export const store: Store<CombinedState<{
  global: GlobalStateShape;
}>, SetSelectedAccount> = createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancer);
```

**global_reducer.ts:**

```
export const globalReducer = (
  state = GLOBAL_INITIAL_STATE,
  action: GlobalActionTypes
): GlobalStateShape =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case GlobalActions.SET_SELECTED_ACCOUNT: {
        draft.selectedAccountId = action.payload.accountId;
        break;
      }
    }
  });
```

**actions.ts**

```
const SET_SELECTED_ACCOUNT = 'SET_SELECTED_ACCOUNT';

export const GlobalActions = {
  SET_SELECTED_ACCOUNT,
};

export interface SetSelectedAccount {
  type: typeof SET_SELECTED_ACCOUNT;
  payload: { accountId: string; selectedApp: AppsList };
}

export type GlobalActionTypes = SetSelectedAccount;
```

---

FWIW, if I add a 2nd Action, then `SetSelectedAccount` turns into returned type above of `GlobalActionTypes` which is the same result & error message about mismatching `dispatch`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is the return type on your `createTestStore` function.  You creating a store a a specific type (`Store<CombinedState<{ global: GlobalStateShape; }>, SetSelectedAccount >`) and then you are returning it as just `Store` with no generics.  The default type for `Store` is the `Store<any, AnyAction>` which you see in your error message.

You might think that this wouldn't be a problem because your store is more specific, so it should be assignable to `Store`, right?   But specificity gets backwards when you are dealing with function arguments like those of `Dispatch`.  The return type says that you are returning a store which is capable of dispatching `AnyAction`, but in reality you are only capable of dispatching the type `SetSelectedAccount`, so your store is not assignable to the broader type.

### Solutions

The easiest thing to do is just remove that return type `: State` entirely.  You've already typed the `store` variable which you are returning, so you don't really need it.

You could also move the type annotation from the variable `store` to the function return.  FYI the redux `CombinedState` utility type doesn't really do anything, `CombinedState<{ global: GlobalStateShape; }>` is the same as `{ global: GlobalStateShape; }`

```
export function createTestStore(isInternal: boolean): Store<{ global: GlobalStateShape; }, SetSelectedAccount> {
    return createStore(rootReducer, {
        global: getGlobalInitialState(isInternal)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I included the shown return types, such as `Store<CombinedState<{ global: GlobalStateShape; }>, SetSelectedAccount >` just to help show what the TSLinter is thinking the type is.

I need to declare a return type with linting setups, and it turns out `Store<{ global: GlobalStateShape }, GlobalActionTypes>` works as you suggested.  One more question for you @Linda Paiste : what happens if I add a 2nd `store` to be returned?   Will the dispatch return type look like a union?  
`Store<{ global: GlobalStateShape, another: AnotherStateShape }, GlobalActionTypes | AnotherActionType>`?